# C# Show only one specific panel?

Tags: hide, panel, visible

c# Windows Form:

Is there a way to make a button that shows one specific panel and hides all others ?

Something like this:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
            !panel1.Visible = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps loop through the `Controls` collection on the form and set all `Panel` controls to hidden before displaying the one you want.  Something like:

```
private void HidePanels()
{
    foreach (var control in Controls)
        if (control is Panel)
            ((Panel)control).Visible = false;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HidePanels();
    panel1.Visible = true;
}
```

This may not prove reliable if you have panels nested within other controls.  It's been a while since I've used forms, so I can't say with much certainty how likely that is.  But one thing you *can* do is keep an *explicit* list of panels on which you want to apply your logic.  Something like this:

```
private IEnumerable<Panel> _panels;
private IEnumerable<Panel> Panels
{
    get
    {
        if (_panels = null)
            _panels = new List<Panel>
             {
                 Panel1,
                 Panel2,
                 Panel3,
                 // etc...
             }
        return _panels;
    }
}
```

Then loop through that instead of the `Controls` collection:

```
private void HidePanels()
{
    foreach (var panel in Panels)
        panel.Visible = false;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HidePanels();
    panel1.Visible = true;
}
```

This would remove any potential for error in the type casting as well as give you more explicit control over which panels to show or hide, since you may want to use panels for other things unrelated to the ones being shown/hidden in this operation.